# Getting TypeError when trying to convert in-memory image to base64 string?

Tags: python, django, base64, dajax

I'm getting URL through POST via DAJAX.

The URL is then passed into the function below. A TypeError is thrown.

I do not want to save the 'img' to disk and then reopen it to do the conversion.

I'm not sure what else to try so I figured I as the world. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
def getqrcode(link):
    bsettings = Bitcoinsettings.objects.get(pk=1)
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H, box_size=bsettings.qrcodesize , border=5,)
    qr.add_data(link)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, 'GIF')
    contents = output.getvalue()
    data = base64.b64encode(open(contents,'rb').read())
    data = "data:image/png;base64," + data
    output.close()
    img = []
    return data

TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Here is the ajax.py code.

```
from torgap.bitcoin.bitcoin import getqrcode
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from dajax.core import Dajax
@dajaxice_register
def getimage(request, image):
    try:
        dajax = Dajax()
        link = image
        image = getqrcode(link)
        dajax.assign('#qrcode', 'src', image)
        return dajax.json()
    except Exception as e: 
        print e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand what returns `ouput.getvalue()` since you are trying to read the file again with

```
data = base64.b64encode(open(contents,'rb').read())
```

but in the line above `contents` already contains a string representation of the image file. And it is almost sure that here is where are hidden the annoying **NULL bytes** that `file()` complains about.

Try change the line above by:

```
 data = base64.b64encode(contents)
```

Also you can give a look at [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) reference.